# Using Flexbox with Media Queries to style <ul>

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox (and Sass) and media queries to style my site. This is the first website I have ever styled.

The desktop and tablet version have a nav that's a ul, styled like this:

```
nav#main-nav {
width: 30%;
padding-right: 3em;

ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    flex-direction: column;

    li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

The nav displays a vertical list, which is exactly what I want.

However, on mobile, I'd like the list to switch from being a vertical list to a horizontal list.

I'm am seriously stumped on how to re-style this element. I have tried changing the flex direction from column to row, and nothing happens.

I have also tried ordering all the li's, but that doesn't seem to work either.

[This](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has been my main point of reference, but I'm not quite sure how to figure this out.

Any ideas?

Comment: flex-direction will only have an effect if the container has `display: flex;` applied.  If that's not outside your snippet, add that, then set your new flex-direction in the media query.  (It always helps to post a complete example, maybe in a jsfiddle)

Comment: Can we see your markup, or better yet, a complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
    ul {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/littleguy230/pen/wBrBvP

Resize the window to less than 500px wide to see the effect.

Comment: [Here's](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) an article about media queries if you want to do some more reading on that. That's essentially what drives the "add styling when the window is a certain width" code.